# Google Spreadsheet - How to copy cell data from one sheet to a cell in another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to implement the function which will copy the value from particular cell on sheet 1 to a particular cell on sheet 2. Below is the code -

```
function RecordEOD() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var inv    = sheet1.getRange("R2").getValue(); // this is inventory price
  var cm_inv = sheet1.getRange("S2").getValue(); // this is inventory @ store
  var curr   = sheet1.getRange("T2").getValue(); //took pl data which we want to store
  var ind  = sheet1.getRange("V2").getValue(); // took nifty value which we want to store
  var cell2 = sheet2.getRange("J2")




  inv.setValues((cell2),{contentsOnly:true});

     //inv.copyTo(sheet1.getRange("J2"), {contentsOnly:true}); 
     //var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A10:G10");
     //var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:G1");
     //ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
     //sheet2.getRange(row, 2).setValue(nifty );



}
```

Tried various formulas I could find on stackoverflow but none helped.

Sample error for every function tried -

TypeError: Cannot find function setValues in object 2108427.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRange` gives you a Range object. `getRange().getValue()` gives you the value (which won't have a `setValues` method). And `setValues' requires an array as it's first argument.

You could try this

```
...
var inv   = sheet1.getRange("R2");
var cell2 = sheet2.getRange("J2").getValue();

inv.setValue(cell2);
```

btw. the api documentation for the Range class is at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Thank you for the answer @SpiderPig but trying the solution removed the inv value and pasted nothing in cell2. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Got it.. wanted the inv to be in cell2 and wrote it vice versa.